# Building a Windows App with iPhone/Android remote control

Tags: c#, winforms, slideshow, mobile-development

I want to build a windows app and I would like to be able to send and receive communication to and from the windows desktop app and mobile devices. For instance I would like to be able to scan the wifi network, see my app (from the mobile device and I would build in security measures) and then be able to change a slide for instance, or change text on the screen... so a remote control for a presentation for example.

Would it be best to build a web service in the windows app and have the mobile app scan for that service and send POST and GET commands? Is there a framework that would help with this already out there?

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and C# and looking to NOT use Powerpoint

Comment: Why the downvote? I searched for answers to this and tried to be as clear as possible. How do I ask this type of question otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many web frameworks for this reason. I would recommend Django if you are familiar with python or Golang if you are familiar with c++. (Golang is a language not a framework) 
If you write a server with HTTP POST and GET then you can access your server with a web browser in any device. 
If you want to have an specific app which communicates with your server you must write a client for your server. Since your server and client are separate, They can be in different languages for example I have written a server with Golang and a client with Qt.